# How to properly extract params from a URL in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have created a webpage to display a profile. By default, the profile page load the user information but I can also load information from another user if I call the profile page with the associated user id.

the URL is `/profile` or can be `/profile?id=12334`

In my code, I have simply did this to add the id in the URL when the button is clicked:

`<a href="/profile?id=123123">`

my profile page for now is just rendering fake data but I do not know how to extract the id and check if the `id` is there and not empty.

```
import React from 'react';
import './Profile.css';

import UserProfile from '../assets/fake/studentinfo'
import TextContents from '../assets/translations/TextContents';
import Gallery from 'react-grid-gallery';
import DetailReview from '../components/materialdesign/DetailReview';
import {Tabs, Tab}  from 'react-bootstrap';
import EmptyTile from '../components/EmptyTile';


class Profiles extends React.Component{

    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {isUserAccount: true, userId: '', userInfo: UserProfile.User1.values};
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let { id } = useParams();
        if((id!==null) && (id !== '')) {
            this.setState({userId: id})
            this.setState({isUserAccount: false})
            this.fetchData(id);
        }
    }

    fetchData = id => {
        this.setState({userInfo: UserProfile.User2.values})
    };


    render(){
        

        const IMAGES =
        [{
                src: "https://c2.staticflickr.com/9/8817/28973449265_07e3aa5d2e_b.jpg",
                thumbnail: "https://c2.staticflickr.com/9/8817/28973449265_07e3aa5d2e_n.jpg",
                thumbnailWidth: 156,
                thumbnailHeight: 156
        },
        {
                src: "https://c2.staticflickr.com/9/8356/28897120681_3b2c0f43e0_b.jpg",
                thumbnail: "https://c2.staticflickr.com/9/8356/28897120681_3b2c0f43e0_n.jpg",
                thumbnailWidth: 156,
                thumbnailHeight: 156
        },
        
        {
                src: "https://c4.staticflickr.com/9/8887/28897124891_98c4fdd82b_b.jpg",
                thumbnail: "https://c4.staticflickr.com/9/8887/28897124891_98c4fdd82b_n.jpg",
                thumbnailWidth: 156,
                thumbnailHeight: 156
        },
        {
            src: "https://c2.staticflickr.com/9/8356/28897120681_3b2c0f43e0_b.jpg",
            thumbnail: "https://c2.staticflickr.com/9/8356/28897120681_3b2c0f43e0_n.jpg",
            thumbnailWidth: 156,
            thumbnailHeight: 156
        }]

        return(
            <div className="profile-container">
                <div className="profile-header" 
                    style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${UserProfile.User1.values.profileHeaderImag})`}}>
                        <img 
                        src={UserProfile.User1.values.profileImg} 
                        alt="profileImg"
                        className="profile-header-image-user"/>                    
                </div>
                <div className="profile-content">
                    <h1> {UserProfile.User1.values.name} </h1>
                    <h3> {UserProfile.User1.values.city}  </h3>
                    <h2> {TextContents.Biography} </h2>
                    <p> {UserProfile.User1.values.bio}  </p>
                    <h2> {TextContents.PhotosVideos} </h2>
                    <div className="profile-gallery">
                        <Gallery id="ReactGridGallery" images={IMAGES}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="profile-tabs">
                    <Tabs defaultActiveKey="profile" id="uncontrolled-tab-example">
                        <Tab eventKey="yourclasses" title="Your Classes">
                            <div>
                            <EmptyTile text={TextContents.CreateYourOwnClass} url="/createaclass"/>
                            </div>
                        </Tab>
                        <Tab eventKey="joinedclasses" title="Joined Classes">
                        <div>
                            <EmptyTile text={TextContents.DiscoverANewExp} url="/createaclass"/>
                        </div>
                        </Tab>
                        <Tab eventKey="bookmarks" title="Bookmarks">
                        <p> {TextContents.NoBookMarkYet} </p>
                        </Tab>
                        <Tab eventKey="yourhosting" title="Your Hosting">
                        <div>
                            <EmptyTile text={TextContents.HaveBusinessOrHome} url="/createahost"/>
                        </div>
                        </Tab>
                    </Tabs>
                </div>
                <div className="profile-content">
                    <h2>{TextContents.Reviews}</h2>
                        {
                            UserProfile.User1.values.reviews.map((review_item, i) => {
                                return (<DetailReview data={review_item} />);
                            })
                        }
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }   
}

export default Profiles;
```

the data will be replaced by the proper one later but for now, I just want to make sure I can easily extract the id if it's there from the URL

Thanks

Comment: Are you using react-router-dom?

Comment: @Petrogad yes but I am probably not using properly. I just declared the route in the app.js

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [react-router-dom](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start) You can use some of their hooks to deconstruct things out of the url.

In this case the hook you're looking for is [`useParams`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams)

`const { id } = useParams();`

If you're using a class component; you can use the [higher order component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) [withRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) or you could use [matchPath](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/matchPath.md) if you have the path you're matching ahead of time.

Comment: So it;s complaining @petrogad

I have added the error: Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Comment: @seb Ah; you'd need to create a function component vs a class component. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html I'll update my answer to how you do it with a class component.

Comment: Not sure to get it. Sorry I am new in React and JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

[URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) and [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) are what you are after, it doesn't need React, it's native JS. `link.searchParams.get('id')` would be enough, but it depends on your target browsers, so you might need a [polyfill](https://github.com/ungap/url-search-params#readme) in your code, otherwise:

```
const {searchParams} = new URL(a.href);
if (searchParams.has('id')) {
  // do your thing with ...
  console.log(searchParams.get('id'));
}
```